# Geometric Interpretation for Eigen value = 0

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

While looking at the geometric interpretation of eigen vectors, I was struck on eigen values as 0!

From $Ax = λx$
we can see that the **Linear transformation** of $A$ has done something to our non-zero vector $x$ and made it **0**.

One possibility I can see is when $Range(Ax)$ is almost **$n-1$** dimensional and X is a vector perpendicular to this $(n-1)$ dimensional space. Then $AX=0$ and $λ=0$ here.

So, when 0 is an eigen value, is it always the case that the $Range(Ax)$ is orthogonal to eigen space corresponding to eigen value 0.

Is it always the case? And is it the right way to think of? Also could you give any other situation than projection, where the matrix $A$ can make a non-zero vector 0?

Thank you!

Comment: For a counterexample, consider $A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. Then $\lambda = 0$ is an eigenvalue with associated eigenvector $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$. The range of $A$ is the the subspace consisting of all multiples of $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$. These subspaces are not orthogonal.

Comment: You might be interested in learning the "four subspaces" theorem, which Gilbert Strang emphasizes in his books. The four subspaces associated with a real matrix $A$ are $R(A), N(A), R(A^T)$, and $N(A^T)$. The four subspaces theorem tells us that $R(A)$ is the orthogonal complement of $N(A^T)$ and $N(A)$ is the orthogonal complement of $R(A^T)$. Strang draws a picture to illustrate this.

Comment: @Bungo The example is great! Thanks! But can you guide me on the geometric meaning of the Linear transformation of the matrix. I know it is squishing 2-D space into 1-D, where both x-axis basis and y-axis transforms to x=1 & y=0. But what the transformation is? And how its different from projection? It is trying to project any vector from 2-D space to the 1-D space corresponding to span of vector $[1 , 0 ]^T$ ?

Comment: @littleO Thanks! And yes I apologize for skipping that lecture of Sir Gilbert Strang. I will watch that at the earliest and then will come again to the question.

Comment: @BhartenduKumar Any real $2 \times 2$ matrix is characterized by how it maps the unit circle. If the matrix has full rank, then the image of the unit circle will be an ellipse. If the matrix has rank 1 (as in my example above), the image of the unit circle will be a line segment (degenerate ellipse). Note that any nonzero $2 \times 2$ matrix that has zero as an eigenvalue will have rank 1. Yes, this is a projection matrix, as can be confirmed by computing that $A^2 = A$. It is projecting $\mathbb R^2$ onto the subspace spanned by $[1,0]^T$, just as you said.

Comment: Note that $A$ is not an *orthogonal* projection because $A^T \neq A$. Therefore it is an [oblique projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)#Oblique_projection).

Comment: Another perspective: note that the eigenvectors associated with eigenvalues $0$ and $1$, which are $[1,-1]^T$ and $[1,0]$ respectively, form a basis for $\mathbb R^2$. Therefore any arbitrary vector can be expressed in the form $v = a[1,-1]^T + b[1,0]^T$, where $a$ and $b$ are scalars. Then $A$ maps $v$ to $Av = aA[1,-1]^T + bA[1,0]^T = b[1,0]^T$. Thus $A$ preserves the component of $v$ in the $[1,0]^T$ direction, and squashes the component in the $[1,-1]^T$ direction down to zero.

Comment: @Bungo I am partly able to see what you are trying to do here (And You have exactly identified by difficulty). So, Matrix as a Transformation applied to a Vector will result in a (another) vector. When the Range is a vector span i.e. 1-D, what I was visualizing as Projecting to this Range vector span, was that the input vector will have 2 orthogonal components (2-D basis), one in direction of Range vector and another orthogonal to it. The vectors orthogonal to Range Vector Span will have 0 vector after projection. But here as you showed, the vector  $[1,-1]^T$ is not orthogonal to $[1,0]$.

Comment: So, how here Matrix Transformation on vector as projections could be working so as to, perform a projection of $[1,-1]^T$ on $[1,0]$ to be zero. As from the geometric perspective, always a vector in span of $[1,-1]^T$ will have a non-zerocomponent in the direction of $[1,0]$  and thus non-zero projection. But somehow shifting basis from orthogonal basis to $oblique$ basisis making it behave just as orthogonal basis behave?